# Django accessible from the local pc where Django stored, but not accessible from another local device

Tags: django, reactjs

I'm building an application using `React TSX` for the front-end side and `Django` for the back-end side. So the application is working properly and it is accessible from my local PC by `localhost:5000` because the application is stored on that PC, the `React TSX` app and the `Django` backend files. But whenever I try to access the application from other local devices, my Mobile or Tablet, I keep getting `Network Error` from the `catch` of `axios`. I have tried a lot of ways but I'm still not able to grant access from `Django` or `React TSX`. So any help will be great guys. Thanks.

`settings.py`

```
..........
..........

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = ["GET","POST"]
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [ "accept", "accept-encoding", "authorization", "content-type", "dnt", "origin", "user-agent", "x-csrftoken", "x-requested-with" ]

CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True

..........
..........
```

Comment: Are you hosting your site on the web or you're running locally? If you are running your server locally, you won't be able to access your site on other devices as every devices' local address -- despite having the same IP -- are different (can't explain exactly).

Comment: Yeah, I'm running my app locally using `localhost:5000` on my PC. When I access my app through the mobile using the PC's IP address `192.168.1.104:5000`, the application opens with the UI displaying but none of the `axios` requests to the `Django` backend files work.

Comment: I will suspect that your computer blocked your phone's request as it's dangerous to leak your IP publicly, but if you want to change that it puts your computer in danger. You might need to host your web on a service like [python anywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/)

Comment: But my mobile and PC are both connected through the same network. So I cannot configure `Django` to fix my problem?

Comment: I don't think there is.